# How to render templates in one region with Iron Router (Meteor)

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, iron-router

My goal is to dynamically create a navigation menu on a Meteor website.

I have a classic menu with static links and the yield where I want the other links to be inserted when needed :

```
<nav id="menu">
    <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>

    {{> yield "navLinks"}}
</nav>
```

-

```
// module_posts.js
Router.onAfterAction(function(){
    if (userIsAdmin()) {
        this.render('postsMenu', { to: 'navLinks' });
    }
});

// module_users.js
Router.onAfterAction(function(){
    if (userIsAdmin()) {
        this.render('usersMenu', { to: 'navLinks' });
    }
});
```

The problem is for example, when an admin is connected, each module (posts, roles, categories...) should insert its own links into that region, but what happens is that each module is rendering over the previous one and removing the links added by another module, so the region seems to only accept one template to be rendered in.

Maybe I am doing it wrong, so please give me a clean solution.

***-- EDIT --***

Okay, maybe a better explanation :
I have several modules (posts, users, roles, etc) that can be enabled or disabled, each of them has a navigation menu to manage it.

Now I want to display their menu in one unique region named {{nav}}.
So I would have to write code somewhere in each module to append their menu in the {{nav}} region if the module is enabled.

I really want to use templates to do that because I could build logics directly into them instead of using collections to store links.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/spacebars-secrets-exploring-meteor-new-templating-engine/). It may provide you some insight.

Comment: Before I provide an answer, I am wondering, do you only want these 'navLinks' to be added to a list of navigation links once the user has navigated to a certain page, or do you want them to all be added immediately on application load? Adding them dynamically versus altogether at application load will determine the solution that you require for this problem.

Comment: @n4tiv3pwnst4r : I want to display the post links when for example the URL matches **/admin/posts/***, I don't want to see them anytime, just when I need them.

Comment: If my answer provides a solution for your question, please be sure to mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are seeing the issue that you are is because of the fact that you are using the `Router.onAfterAction()` function to render your menu templates. The problem with this is that the `Router.onAfterAction()` function applies globally to all routes and runs whenever a new route is run. This is why you are only seeing the navigation links from the final defined navigation links definition, which in the case of your question above would be the `usersMenu` navigation links. Instead, you want to define your navigation menu template rendering logic for each route that you want it to differ on. Also, you do not want to use the `onAfterAction()` function, because this is intended to be used for post-processing once your route has actually been run. In order to achieve what you would like, you would do the following:

```
Router.route('/admin/posts', {
    ...
    yieldRegions: {
        'postsMenu': {to: 'navLinks'}
    }
    ...
});

Router.route('/admin/users', {
    ...
    yieldRegions: {
        'usersMenu': {to: 'navLinks'}
    }
    ...
});
```

So, as you can see, we have defined a route definition for each of your unique routes as specified in your question, one for admin posts and one for admin users. In order to specify specific templates to be rendered into named `yield`s for a given route, you should use the `yieldRegions` route option. In it, you specify the name of each template that you would like to render into which named yield region. This is where you specify your templates from your question.

If you would like to read about all of the route specific options that are available when defining a route definition, please take a look [here](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-options).

Comment: Thank you, but in fact it does not resolve my problem, I mean, Yes the corresponding menu is shown on the right page BUT, the thing is I cannot append other links to {{navLinks}} after having rendered into it so how to do that ? **I was talking about modules, each modules has its own links, so they should be able to render links to the same region {{navLinks}}.**